# Rapidjson parsing array

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I am trying to use rapidjson library to parse a json string with an array of objects, like the example below, but once I get reference to the "docs" elements even though the "assert(IsArray)" goes fine, it fails when I try to iterate over the array because when I invoke the function "Size()" it fails.

```
{

"response":{"docs":[
      {
        "eircode":"D02 YN32",
        "loc":"53.3440763,-6.2356984",
        "addr":"ACCENTURE, 7 HANOVER QUAY, DUBLIN 2",
        "geodist()":462.40406697863784
      },
      {
        "eircode":"N37 Y985",
        "loc":"53.4243401,-7.9216913",
        "addr":"ATHLONE COMMUNITY SCHOOL, RETREAT ROAD, ATHLONE, CO. WESTMEATH",
        "geodist()":569.0322899541842}
      }
      ]

}
```

This is my C++ code:

```
const Value& response = d["response"];
assert(response.IsObject());

assert(response.HasMember("docs"));

const Value& docs_list = response["docs"];
assert(docs_list.IsArray());

for (int i=0; i<docs_list.Size(); i++)
{
    //something here
}
```

And the error I get:

`rapidjson/document.h:1128: rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::ConstMemberIterator rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::MemberEnd() const [with Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>; rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::ConstMemberIterator = rapidjson::GenericMemberIterator<true, rapidjson::UTF8<>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<> >]: Assertion 
'IsObject()' failed.
    Aborted`

Could someone help me on this ? Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as C/C++ - this is C++ code, please remove the C tag

Comment: And the JSON you posted is malformed - the closing bracket `]` (of `"docs"`) is **after** the closing brace `}` of `"response"`

Comment: the real json I am using is fine, I just copy a small portion manually, and maybe I made the mistake of closing the array in the wrong position. As I said, the code is parsing the json fine, and I can get reference to the response and doc Value&, but when I invoke the function "Size()" it fails, If I do not invoke that function it is working fine. Could someone with experience with rapidjson help please ?